# How can I map Super + UpArrow to PageUp?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, shortcut-keys

I'd like to map

- <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>UpArrow</kbd> to <kbd>PageUp</kbd>
- <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>DownArrow</kbd> to <kbd>PageDown</kbd>
- <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> to <kbd>Home</kbd>
- <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd> to <kbd>End</kbd>

on an Apple aluminum wireless keyboard. Those who know the keyboard would note that it already does these with the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key by default; that's fine, and I'd like to keep that, but be able to do the same with a one-handed key combination as well, hence my wanting the <kbd>Super</kbd> mappings.

I've been searching around for a possible way to do this via xmodmap for 3 hours, yet nothing has worked.

Answer (score 7):

try editing your /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc keyboard definition

(this will change your bindings globally, if you want something more fine tuned, there is some more work to do, like creating a custom keymap or a custom variant)

as you can see here:

```
key  {        [  Prior                ]       };
key  {        [  Next                 ]       };
```

as you can see the key PGUP is bound to "Prior". While:

```
 key  {        [  Left                 ]       };
 key  {        [  Down                 ]       };
```

LEFT and DOWN keys are bound to "Left" and "Down".

The part between brackets `[ ]` is a list of symbols to be generated. You can put more than one. The first one is the symbol associated with the unmodified key, while other positions are for symbols associated with the key + some modifier.

Commonly it's used to define the behavior of the key plus the "SHIFT" modifier:

```
  key  {        [         l,    L               ]       };
  key  {        [ semicolon,    colon           ]       };
```

But also other modifiers can be specified, for example in the esperanto map (epo):

```
  key   { [ jcircumflex,  Jcircumflex,  bracketleft,   braceleft  ] };
  key   { [ hcircumflex,  Hcircumflex,  bracketright,  braceright ] };
```

you can type a [ character by typing AltGr + key  (the [ key on the us keymap), and { by Shift+AltGr + key .

So far so good. The sequence we can understand from looking at some simple examples is:

`plain shift altgr shift+altgr`

---

However, we want to be able to bind our LEFT and RIGHT key to the plain and CTRL+ALT modifiers. How to achieve that?

I have no idea, and never tried, but I'd take inspiration from /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc:

```
xkb_symbols "function" {
    key  {
        type="CTRL+ALT",
        symbols[Group1]= [ F1,  XF86_Switch_VT_1 ]
    };
```

Perhaps we can do the same thing for our arrow keys. Let's try to add the following lines:

```
 key  { type="CTRL+ALT", symbols[Group1]= [  Left, Prior                ]       };
 key  { type="CTRL+ALT", symbols[Group1]= [  Down, Next                 ]       };
```

Just below the original definitions of LEFT and DOWN, in the bottom part of the 'pc' file.

And then restart the X server. Sorry, but I cannot close my session right now to test it.

BTW, you might be interested in http://code.google.com/p/partiwm/wiki/xpra, so that you can restart the X session and still preserve some applications across restarts.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work either. I changed your "CTRL+ALT" to SUPER_R, SUPER, META, since I want to map the right Super key, not CTRL+ALT (which also doesn't work). I also tried adding identifiers after the "key" part (like <PGUP>) which I thought were missing, but no difference.

Answer (score 4):

I've tried something similar using xmodmap and its cognates and didn't succeed. Try `xbindkeys` in conjunction with `xdotool`. This is what I put in `~/.xbindkeysrc` to bind numeric keypad 1 and 2 to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>PageDown</kbd>:

```
"xdotool key ctrl+Prior" 
  Release + KP_End

"xdotool key ctrl+Next" 
  Release + KP_Down
```

Comment: Thanks; I've tried the same, but it doesn't seem to be working. Super + Down seems to emit the "~" character every few presses in the terminal (the normal PageDown does this too, so it led me to think it worked), but it doesn't actually perform PageDown.

Comment: I've also tried xautomation and xvkbd; they both fail the same way. I'm sure the xbindkeys part is working, since I can get the key combinations to launch other apps and so on with it, but the keypresses just don't get emulated.